# Constant "Update Required" notifications from Google Messages for web

Tags: google-messages

I keep getting this notification:

> **Update Required**
>
> To continue receiving messages from your phone, open Messages for web to automatically update to the latest version.

As instructed, I've opened Messages many times.  I've shift-refreshed.  I've restarted my device.  This *still* comes up whenever I close the tab, sometimes 3 or 4 times.  What can I do to make it stop?

In case it matters, I'm using Google Fi for phone service, which makes Messages have other features like phone calling and voicemail.  It feels like a different app than before I switched to Google Fi.

**Edit:** I've tried this on multiple devices, but I've noticed it the most on the latest Chrome OS (99?) using Chrome.  I don't think it's connecting directly to my phone because it's Google Fi, but my phone is on the same network.  I've also tried on an older version of Chrome using Ubuntu and was not immediately able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please add more details like the name and version of the operative system and web-browser that you are using, if your devices are using the same network, if you have tried using different web browsers and different devices.

Comment: @Rubén I've added those details

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. By the way, Chrome (web browser, I assume that OS too) current version is 100. According to a Mexican guy that I follow in Tik Tok because the version number has three digits some "old" web pages might have a problem... besides trying with old Chrome version, try using a different web-browser and checkout the official Google Messages, Google-Fi and Google Chrome communities ( https://support.google.com/messages/community , https://support.google.com/fi/community , https://support.google.com/chrome/community  )

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem for the last few weeks (using a chromebook) Tried reinstalls etc. Finally went to check me chrome version and I was on 99.. Normally I get update messages and I always take them - but I must not have gotten get a message to update to the latest - which I ran a check for and it was 100..something - so I got and  - but problem persisted. But next I did the uninstall/reinstall for Messages again and this time it fixed it.

Comment: Can you explain how you uninstalled/reinstalled?  I'm using Messages within a browser tab.

Comment: I actually had the PWA installed but it opens in a tab.  I've tried uninstalling it.  Maybe it will work.  :)

Comment: To uninstall/reinstall - In Chromebook - swipe up to see all your apps. Right click on messages app and you get an uninstall option. Then go to Play Store and Install it again. Make sure Messages app is not in the top list of little icons - for some reason right click doesnt work on those icons.